# Joining on nearest timestamp in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, json, mongodb-3.2

**MongoDB version: 3.2.11**

Coming from using primarily PostgreSQL, I am new to MongoDB and am having trouble constructing complex queries in the required JSON format (where in SQL I would use CTEs). To provide a simplified example - there are a number of cars with their own unique identifier `vin`.  The cars ping when they are reserved, **and** when they are not reserved.

I have a number Objects in my collection `engine` that are structured like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "vin" : "12345",
    "class_name" : "foo",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329250,
        "status" : "LOCKED"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
    "vin" : "12345",
    "class_name" : "foo",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329260,
        "status" : "LOCKED"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
    "vin" : "12345",
    "class_name" : "bar",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329270,
        "status" : "UNLOCKED",
        "reservation_id" : "71"

    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4"),
    "vin" : "12345",
    "class_name" : "baz",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329280,
        "status" : "UNLOCKED",
        "reservation_id" : "71"

    }
}    
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5"),
    "vin" : "12345",
    "class_name" : "foo",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329290,
        "status" : "NO SIGNAL"

    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6"),
    "vin" : "12345",
    "class_name" : "foo",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329300,
        "status" : "LOCKED"

    }
}
```

Records produced outside of a reservation are always of class `foo` (those *during* a reservation can vary but are never `foo`)

I am interested only in retrieving the `status` immediately before and immediately after each reservation on each vin.  This can be retrieved by taking the closest record of class `foo` to the min timestamp per `reservation_id` and `vin`,  as my objective is to retrieve all of the before/after statuses for each `reservation_id` made on each `vin`

The output for the above example would be something like

`{"vin": "1234", "reservation_id": "71", "pre_status": "LOCKED", "post_status": "NO SIGNAL"}`

So far I have this to get the reservations themselves, but would appreciate any recommendations on how to proceed further - would a `forEach` statement be appropriate in the above case?

```
db.getCollection('engine').find({"decoded_payload.reservation_id": {$exists: true}})
```